# Task 'build' not found in root project 'workspace'. Some candidates are: 'build'

Tags: android-studio, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am unable to build a project using gradle 2.10, i have tried with different versions but the issue is the same.

i am using jenkins 2.10 version.  The same project can be build by android studio.

Can some one help me with the Jenkins configuration, i have defined SDK path, have gradle plugin etc.

```
[ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
[ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Task 'built' not found in root project 'workspace'. Some candidates are: 'build'.
* Try:
[ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Run gradle tasks to get a list of available tasks. 
20:11:26.063 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * Exception is:
20:11:26.063 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] org.gradle.execution.TaskSelectionException: Task 'built' not found in root project 'workspace'. Some candidates are: 'build'.
```

I have simply added attached step in the build, do i need to add another steps for building ?
[image]

Comment: Are you sure you have a gradle task called "built" and that you dont mean "build"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no **built** task, try **build**, this should solve your problem.

However, It's a good practice to parametrize your job, you can use **assembleDebug** and **assembleRelease** tasks. This way you can trigger builds for automated integration tests and builds for production separately without having to duplicate jobs.

Define parameters using [Parametrized trigger plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin).

Example of parameters usage in the Gradle Tasks area:

```
 $BUILD_PROFILE
 -PKEYSTORE_PATH=$SIGNING_KEYSTORE_PATH
 -PKEYSTORE_ALIAS=$KEYSTORE_ALIAS
 -PKEYSTORE_PASSWORD=$SIGNING_PASSWORD
```

In your **build.gradle** file you can add the section:

```
signingConfigs {
    release {
        storeFile file(getPropertyFromBuildCommand("KEYSTORE_PATH"))
        storePassword getPropertyFromBuildCommand("KEYSTORE_PASSWORD")
        keyAlias getPropertyFromBuildCommand("KEYSTORE_ALIAS")
        keyPassword getPropertyFromBuildCommand("KEYSTORE_PASSWORD")
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}
```

This if properly set could produce the command for example:

```
gradle assembleRelease -PKEYSTORE_ALIAS=prodKey -PKEYSTORE_PATH=/home/jenkins/my-prod-keys.jks -PKEYSTORE_PASSWORD=yourPassword
```

This will build a signed apk for production and submission on the google play store you can use [flexible publish](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Flexible+Publish+Plugin) or [conditional build step](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin) to branch your build flows.

Comment: i am sorry ..but i am unable to understand the 1st line 'There's no built task, try build, this should solve your problem.'... my android project doesn't have any task called 'BUILT'. how do i resolve this .. thanks for the plugin information

Comment: @TanajiPadwal Read your **Tasks** line in the jenkins configurations screenshot you provided, it's written buil**t** --stacktrace --debug, with a **T** in the end, it should be buil**d** --stacktrace --debug with **D**.

Comment: @TanajiPadwal [How to accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)